# How to send data from Google sheets to Firestore Cloud?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to send data from the google spreadsheet to my Firestore database (with this [library](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript)), but the result has been strange. Take a look below:

My script - Google Apps Script

```
function firestore() {

   // Firestore setup
   const email = "xxxxxxxxxx";
   const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXXXXXXXXXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
   const projectId = "xxxxxx";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);

   // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Orçamento";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;


   // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){

     var data = [];

     data.push({
      "id": sourceData[i][0],
      "data": sourceData[i][1],
      "acao": sourceData[i][2],
      "categoria": sourceData[i][3],
      "movimentos": sourceData[i][4],
      "descricao": sourceData[i][5]
   });

   firestore.createDocument("orcamento",data);

  }

}
```

That works, but there's something wrong with the data at Firestore.
Take a look below:

My Firestore
[image]

When the data is sent to the Firestore database it creates a "Map".

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be with this (it creates an array):

```
 var data = [];
```

You may want to try:

```
  var data = {};
  data.id = sourceData[i][0];
  data.data = sourceData[i][1];
  data.acao = sourceData[i][2];
  data.categoria = sourceData[i][3];
  data.movimentos = sourceData[i][4];
  data.descricao = sourceData[i][5];
```

... instead of

```
     var data = [];

     data.push({
      "id": sourceData[i][0],
      "data": sourceData[i][1],
      "acao": sourceData[i][2],
      "categoria": sourceData[i][3],
      "movimentos": sourceData[i][4],
      "descricao": sourceData[i][5]
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix the problem, just modify your last line like this:

```
firestore.createDocument("orcamento/" + i ,data);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).